# undefined method `time_ago_in_words' for #<Post:0xac200b0> in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following code in **views/posts/show.html.erb**:

```
  <span><%= @post.time_ago_in_words(Time.now) %></span><br />
```

And I get this error:

```
undefined method `time_ago_in_words' for #<Post:0xac200b0>
```

Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[time_ago_in_words](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_ago_in_words) is an Helper. It's not an ActiveModel instance method. So you have to call it this way(the field is up to you):

```
 <span><%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %></span><br />
```

By the way, calculating this kind of stuff is not a [best practise](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/105-not-use-time_ago_in_words). I recommend you to take a look at a solution like [jquery.timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/).

Comment: I'm curious, why is not a best practice?

Comment: @alexchenco The link in the answer gives a nice explanation of the problem. tl;dr Use the CPU of the client to do that, furthermore you can cache the HTML that contains the time_ago stuff easily that way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the date of the post is `date_posted`, try:

```
<span><%= time_ago_in_words(Time.now - @post.date_posted) %></span><br />
```